# Как обработать исключения 0 и 1 через try catch?

Tags: c++

Мне нужно что бы если было не равно нулю меня выбрасывало сразу в catch, что бы даже if не успел сработать.

Возможно это сделать?

```
try
{   
    if ((RetVal = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData)) != 0)
    {
        cout << "test" << endl;
    }               
}
catch (const exception& ex)
{
    cout << ex.what() << endl;
}
catch (...)
{
    cout << "error" << endl;
}
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97379/discussion-on-question-by-loli----0--1--try-catch).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как вариант - можно написать класс-обертку для проверки возвращаемого значения:

```
struct WSAException : public std::exception
{
public:
    WSAException(int errorCode)
        : _code(errorCode)
    {

    }

    int get_code() const { return _code; }

    /* .... */

private:
    const int _code;
};


struct check_return
{
    check_return(int return_value)
    {
        if(return_value != 0)
            throw WSAException(return_value);
    }
};



int main()
{
     try
     {
        /* .... */
        check_return{ WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData) };
     }
     catch (const WSAException& ex)
     {
          cout << ex.get_code() << endl;
     }
     catch (...)
     {
          cout << "error" << endl;
     }
     return 0;
}
```

Comment: Думаете, бросать исключение в конструкторе это более приемлемый вариант, чем использование оператора if? Который, кстати, так же здесь используется.

Comment: @isnullxbh Ну если код подразумевает бесконечное дублирование конструкции типа if(ret_val != 0) throw ..., то да. Выброс исключения в конструкторе тот еще вопрос, однако в данном случае, считаю, ничего страшного в этом нет. И, если это так критично, все легко можно переделать в  метод, который проверяет возвращаемое значение. Однако, опять же на мой взгляд, такая конструкция будет выглядеть менее лаконичной

Comment: Понял Вас, спасибо за разъяснения.

Comment: Немного запутался, такое чувство что код стал сложнее, можно попробовать использовать только один класс или структуру?
Как я понял там работает перегрузка

Comment: @loli Можно избавиться от WSAException, тогда в конструктор check_return изменится на ` if(return_value != 0) throw return_value `. Ну и ожидать в блоке catch вам придется int, а не std::exception. Однако, это достаточно плохой вариант. Советую вам для начала познакомиться с исключениями в c++, в частности с std::exception, тогда вам многое станет понятно

Comment: а как WSAException работает чет найти не могу описания или это названия класса)
я запутался
Вижу вызывается struct check_return он проверяет не равно ли нулю верно, если не равно вызывает WSAException, получается все что находится в WSAException можно запихать внутри if?
но почему тогда создан еще класс точнее структура

Comment: @loli WSAException - это пример класса исключений, написанный мной только что. Вы можете использовать любой другой. Реализация данного класса полностью описана в моем ответе. Структура check_return же служит лишь для удобства обработки результата и уменьшения дублирования. Что бы вам каждый раз не писать один и тот же if, вся логика по обработке результата выполнения метода описана тут. Это лишь один из вариантов

Comment: Кажется понял как работает, да это то что нужно, спасибо :)

Comment: @Jester а для чего нужно использовать public std::exception
я проверил код работает без него вроде как.

Comment: Можно еще как то заменить `catch (const WSAException& ex)
        {
            cout << ex.get_code() << endl;
        }`
На общий класс например test а внутри этого класса как раз и вызывать то что нужно WSAException или что то еще

Comment: @loli Вообще это не то что бы обязательно, однако наследование от std::exception является правилом хорошего тона. Например, если выбрасывать множество разных типов, вам обязательно придется писать catch для каждого типа. Тем самым вы лишаете себя возможности как-то обобщить код.

Comment: @loli Если говорить о замене, вы можете ловить не WSAException, а std::exception. И в блоке catch выводить только сообщение: `catch(std::exception& ex) { std::cout << ex.what(); }`. В данном примере вы, допустим, можете формировать строку, которая будет выводить сообщение об ошибке по коду. Для этого достаточно переопределить метод std::exception::what(...)

Comment: У меня идея пошла дальше, если использовать виртуальный класс тогда код станет более читаемый а в catch передать как раз этот виртуальный класс

Comment: @Jester я поэкспериментировал и понял что не подходит такой вариант, код все равно слишком сложный. Карочи говоря разница не существенная что бы писать так а не через if а еще недостаток в этом коде такой что после ошибки catch он делает несколько лишних итераций переходя с одного класса к другому и т.д что еще больше может запутать человека когда он будет использовать дебагер.

Answer (score 2):

Winsock (WSA, Windows Sockets API) - это программный интерфейс предоставляющий поддержку I/O для сетевых приложений, который существует в виде библиотеки написанной на C. Так в C нет исключений, то и функция [WSAStartup](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock/nf-winsock-wsastartup) не может генерировать последние.

Comment: А как люди создают эти исключения для своего кода?

Comment: @loli, как Вам и написали в комментариях выше - проверяйте возвращаемое функцией WSAStartup значение, и, если оно не нулевое, бросайте исключение.

Comment: Если ставите минус, пожалуйста, оставьте комментарий с конструктивным объяснением, что мной было сказано неверно.

Comment: Наверно кому то не понравилось что вы написали типо это невозможно, просто в программировании нету ничего невозможного, все придумано людьми может быть улучено и сделано еще лучше.

Comment: @loli, постараюсь объяснить еще раз: функция WSAStartup не генерирует исключений, исключение можете выбросить только Вы после проверки возвращаемого функцией значения. И если дать однозначный ответ на Ваш вопрос: нет, нельзя.

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать обертку из макроса, тогда можно будет выяснить где именно возникла проблема:

```
#define CHECK_ERR(expr, text) \
if(!(expr)) \
{               \
    throw std::runtime_error(std::string(text) + " at " + std::string(__FILE__) \
                             + " Line:" + std::to_string(__LINE__));    \
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    WSADATA wsaData;

    try
    {
        CHECK_ERR(WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData) != 0, "WSAStartup != 0");
    }
    catch (const exception& ex)
    {
        cout << ex.what() << endl;
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        cout << "error" << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Вывод такой:

```
WSAStartup != 0 at ..\untitled2\main.cpp Line:24
```

**Дополнено**:
    Если очень важно отображать информацию, где случилась проблема, то придется использовать макросы: `__FILE__` - название файла, `__LINE__` - номер строки, `__FUNCTION__` название функции и из них формировать строку, причем данные макросы должны быть вызваны максимально близко к функции, которая вернула ошибку.

Данные макросы нельзя использовать в каком-то классе обертке, как в примере выше класс `check_return`, потому что при возникновении любой ошибки будет выведен всегда один и тот же файл и строка.
Для обхода это проблемы можно погуглить на тему `StackWalker` - эту штука позволяет "раскрутить стек" и увидеть откуда у нас возникла ошибка, но оно очень компиляторозависиммая и затратное по времени. Раскрутка стека один раз, может занимать ~1 сек.

Comment: А можно не использовать обертку макросов и создать отдельный класс который будет выводить все ошибки с таким выводом?

WSAStartup != 0 at ..\untitled2\main.cpp Line:24
точнее писать на какой линии Line произошла ошибка в файле

Comment: Думаю если объединить с первым вариантом и этот вариант будет что то интересное
Сейчас попробую)

Comment: @loli Дополнил ответ

Comment: По поводу раскрутки стена можно поподробней, это 1 секунду занимает во время компиляции или во время работы программы?

Comment: @loli во время выполнения программы, по-этому такую методику стоит использовать только в отладочных целях, в местах, где ошибка может возникнуть редко и по вине программиста. Такой себе чуть продвинутый аналог ``ASSERT'а``

Comment: Понял, буду знать теперь, спасибо, надеюсь не придется использовать такие штуки )